# Having a postgres function taking an argument and returning a table how to merge many such results into ingle table (SelectMany)?

Tags: postgresql

I want to do something like LINQ SelectMany in Postgres SQL. I have a function with a signature like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION get_objects(id_in int) RETURNS TABLE (name varchar, id_out int)
```

Each call on it returns 200 rows.

I have a select that returns a table of in_IDs. I want to call my function on each row of such a table and merge them into a single one. In other words, join many lists of rows into a single big table. How to do such a thing in Postgres SQL (not inside function loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lateral join.

```sql
select l.* 
from the_table_of_in_ids as t -- or put the query in brackets here 
cross join lateral get_objects(t.id) as l;
```